# Include module contionally in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Consider multiple ActiveRecord classes with overlapping fields and functionality and many of those overlapping fields having the same validation.  I'm attempting to share validation, but not run the shared code if a condition is met (based on one of the Model's non-overlapping attributes).

```rb
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  include SharedValidation
end

class Magazine < ApplicationRecord
  include SharedValidation
end

module SharedValidation
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  validates_presence_of :name, :publisher, :author
end
```

So let's say `Magazine.is_deleted` is a Magazine-only field and we only want to run shared validations if is_deleted is *false*.  Any ideas on how this could be accomplished in the Class?

---

Note: I've attempted to modify the module by performing field detection and evaluation, but am not sure if this makes sense or if it's working:

```rb
module SharedValidation
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  included do
    proc do |rcd|
      has_deleted_field = self.column_names.include?('is_deleted') 
      
      if (has_deleted_field && !rcd.is_deleted) || !has_deleted_field
        validates_presence_of :name, :publisher, :author
      end 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: 1. _Please don't try to evaluate the practicality of the example -- I'm awful at making examples. I've included it above to demonstrate the technical challenge._  
2. There's many more fields and validators than this, this was just an example.  I originally had the validators in each class and am trying to consolidate to reduce the number of errors as names change.

Comment: `validates_*` should be at the class level, right?  have you tried `extend SharedValidation` instead of `include SharedValidation`?

Comment: I suppose a separate question might be - is there a reason, if there is so much overlap, not to use STI with a base class from which you derive 'Book' and 'Magazine'.  If you could do that, then the base class would have the shared validations.  That might not be right for your use case but maybe worth considering.

Comment: @mrrogers good thoughts. I don’t have much lead way over the model/table design. I should add that I think the module validations work insides the `included` block and am not sure inside the `proc`. When I have access to a computer, I’m going to try a custom class function that may be able to call include in the if-block (and take the logic out of the module).

Comment: I think I slightly missed the bit about conditional validations.  That definitely makes things trickier.  I think because those validations sit on the class, that proc may not work.  but maybe if the conditional was defined in the `:if` which you can pass to the `validates_*` methods.   I might take a crack at it.  Super interesting problem.

Comment: `validates_with` is worth further consideration as opposed to `include`-ing a concern  https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/active_record_validations.html#validates-with (v5.2 though others are available)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like instead of including the module conditionally, you can add the conditional to the validation methods (within the SharedModule).

Using your samples:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  include SharedValidations
end

class Magazine < ApplicationRecord
  include SharedValidations
end

module SharedValidations
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  def deleted
    return unless self.class.column_names.include?("is_deleted")

    is_deleted
  end

  included do
    validates :name, :publisher, presence: true, unless: :deleted
  end
end
```

Magazine has `name`, `publisher` and `is_deleted` columns.
Book only has `name` , `publisher` - without `is_deleted`.

And it looks like this setup works.

```
irb> book = Book.new()
=> #<Book id: nil, name: nil, publisher: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb> book.valid?
=> false
irb> book.errors.full_messages
=> ["Name can't be blank", "Publisher can't be blank"]

irb> magazine = Magazine.new
=> #<Magazine id: nil, name: nil, publisher: nil, is_deleted: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb> magazine.valid?
=> false
irb> magazine.errors.full_messages
=> ["Name can't be blank", "Publisher can't be blank"]

irb> magazine.is_deleted=true
=> true
irb> magazine.valid?
=> true
```

Comment: I can’t test this at the moment, but that looks promising. I was really hoping I could wrap the validation under one conditional rather than per-validation. I have quite a few `validates` statements, some are presence, others are value-checks, and some are conditioned on values of other fields. So you can see why it would be nice to be DRYer and evaluate is_deleted once.

Comment: Based on your comments, it was clear that the example is simple and doesn't really show the whole picture.  Because all those validates are class level functions (which later act on instances) programmatically it kind of makes sense that you can't add the conditional before you have an instance ... sort of.  But, with this, at least you can still have all the conditional validation logic in one place.

Comment: I’m sure I’m committing a Railsian faux pas, though I don’t program it much anymore. Honestly, I don’t like separating the validation logic from the class. It feels naughty, but I’m breaking through that hesitation this one time.

Comment: I tested this out and it works beautifully.  I tripped myself up not recognizing the use of `class` in `self.class.column_names`, which I suppose I could use `self.attribute_names`, though I kind of like checking the class for the table schema.  Roger, do you happen to know if `validates ... presence:` is preferred to `validates_presence_of`?  I think the latter is a little older, but I find it easier to read when there are different validators (e.g., `validates_length_of`) for many fields.

Comment: At the risk of cross-pollination, I've also asked a similar setup question that you might find easy/interesting here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69977690/how-to-validate-many-to-many-association-based-on-other-object-in-rails