# How to validate many-to-many association based on other object in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, rails-activerecord

*Note: this is an example created for simplicity based on a more complex implementation.*

Consider a form to submit Renter details, with a subform to add Apartment details.  The Apartment record should only be created if the renter claims to be 18 or older.

### 1-to-1 Apartment Validation based on Renter

In a previous iteration this relationship was 1-to-1 and IDs were stored on objects. I was able to validate the Apartment details based on the Renter information like so:

```rb
class Apartment < ApplicationRecord
  validates :apartment_name, presence: true, if: lambda { |apartment|
    apartment.renter.try(:age) >= 18
  }
```

The association was straight forward. However, with the 3rd join table there may no longer be a linkage.

### N-to-N Apartment Validation based on Renter

Attempting `apartment.renters` in the lambda returns an empty CollectionProxy, I suppose as expected since the apartment record has yet to be created and can't be added to the Rentals table.

Important to note that if a renter (under 17) passes its validation, the Renter record should be created/updated and the Apartment record should not be created (not pass validation). **How should apartment be validated or conditioned on renter object?**  Should this occur in the controller or Renter model?

#### Example Models

```rb
class Apartment < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rentals
  has_many :renters, through: :rentals
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :renters, allow_destroy: true
end

class Renter < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rentals
  has_many :apartments, through: rentals
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :apartments, allow_destroy: true
end

class Rental < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :apartment
  belongs_to :renter
end
```

Comment: I would really model this as an apartment has many rental agreements and the rental agreement has many tenants attached to it (via a join model - aka parties). You would then validate that the rental agreement has at least one tenant over 18. You're completely missing a key part of the puzzle.

Comment: It could be that you should actually ask us about the real question that you're trying to solve even if its more complex as you risk the actual meaning of the question getting lost in translation with overabstraction.

Comment: @max ty, I feel this example is a suitable substitute. I fear any deviation from the concept may be too distracting.  Your initial comment is exactly why I included the top note as an effort to discourage reading into the objects and making suggestions for the business logic.  The desire is to concentrate on the technical coordination involved for the models' relationships and validation criteria.  The gist: a record's validation/creation is dependent value of an associated model that's also in the process of being created.  Is that clearer? I may not have adequately described in question.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a problem that really should be solved with either a model validation or nested attributes due to the obvious catch 22. Rather you should look into something like the interactor pattern.

Comment: @max thank you, I'm unfamiliar with that gem/pattern -- I haven't had to update Rails in a while. I'll take a look as I imagine there is a better solution.  I'm attempting the least configuration as possible.

Comment: Its more of general pattern. An object which has the role of coordinating the interaction between the two objects. It predates Rails.

Comment: As far as answering which model a validation belongs to - there is no simple answer like "its always the parent". Validations just serve to enforce the simple parts of the buisness logic and cannot be decoupled from it - and can get nasty when there is more then one model involved as models do not have any context apart from if the model is being created or updated.

Comment: I've used Form Objects as a pattern when you have multiple models that have interacting validations (maybe like what @max suggests.  I might try to mock something up later but this post at least gives the idea  https://jaryl.medium.com/disciplined-rails-form-object-techniques-patterns-part-1-23cfffcaf429

Comment: @mrrogers thanks, I hadn't considered that.  I'm still reading it, but think I get the concept of a Form object.  It does break my team's conventions/practices and I'm trying to place myself in my shoes 2-4 years from now and having to maintain this and whether I would understand where things live and what they do.  This is just me thinking out loud as I consider it -- it's a provocative idea.

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, I've settled with handling validation errors naturally through the webform with the validation occurring on the Renter object.  This is not a true solution to the asked question, as it postpones the *big* condition of creating the Renter and not the Application -- not fair of me.

It is a simple, typical validation (nothing new) that prevents the creation of both records:

```rb
class Renter < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rentals
  has_many :apartments, through: rentals
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :apartments, allow_destroy: true

  validates_each :apartments do |record, attr, value|
    record.errors.add(attr, 'must be at least 18') if record.age < 18
  end
end
```

I wouldn't have asked the question if I was comfortable with settling on this solution or removing the aforementioned condition. I'll select a better answer if someone addresses it.